# upload a compressed csv file to mysql for appending to a table

Tags: mysql, .net

How do I upload a compressed csv file to a remote mysql instance for appending to a table?

Assume the fields in the csv file correspond to table columns. The first line in the file is a header line.

What nuget package (if any) should I add to my .net solution?

What code is required to connect to the database and send the compressed file to it?

Specifically, this is code running on an AWS EC2 sending the file to a MYSQL database in AWS RDS.

Comment: What do you mean by compressed file? Is it compressed when sent over network e.g. gzip, ...?

Comment: I have the file and can compress it if necessary. The file is 1Gb. Compressed it's a tenth of the size, so it would be good to send a compressed file over the network to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MySQL .NET connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and MySQL statement load data.

If you have only SQL access on machine hosting database you can use this:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=server;uid=username;pwd=xxx;database=db"); 

  try
  {
    conn.Open();
  }
  catch (MySqlException e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to sql server");
  }

  // maybe add transaction, to be sure everything is done      
  MySqlTransaction transaction =  conn.BeginTransaction();

  // read csv line by line
  // I use this csv parser http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader 
  using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), true))
  {
    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
    {   
      try
      { 
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into table ()", conn);
        int affected_rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         transaction.Rollback();
         Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
         break;
      }
    }
  }

  transaction.Commit();
  conn.close();
```

If you can make some webservice on remote machine, I would recommend to use MySQL load data infile syntax. It's very fast.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'csv.txt' INTO TABLE rates IGNORE 1 LINES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```

I suppose you have to decompress csv file before inserting data into table. You can install MySQL .NET connector using [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.8.3):

```
PM> Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.8.3
```

Comment: thanks for the nuget package and sql command ... how do I send the file to the remote database? Is it attached to the command object? Would you be able to add some c# code to go with it please? Sorry I'm just so new at this.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the SQL command as you have provided will get the database to load a file that's already saved on the same machine's file system. In my case, the file is not on the same machine. I'm hoping to send it across to the machine hosting the database. Does that make sense?

Comment: Remote machine hosting the database must process this file. It must have some kind of interface. Interface would be in the form of for example web service i.e. SOAP, REST. You can connect to remote MySQL server using .NET connector and then import data. Importing 1 GB file will take very long time, therefore I suggested MySQL load data infile command on the remote machine side. If you have only SQL access to remote machine then connecting using .NET connector is the only way.

Comment: Found this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.AnySource.html

Comment: In case AWS EC then I believe you have found the solution.

Comment: I think so, thank you broadband, though I have much to learn ... lol I don't even know how to run the commands mentioned in that article.